# Alias for enum value name in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Can I make an alias for enum value name in C# ?
For example I have two files: A and B.

```
public class A
{
    public enum myEnum 
        {
            value_1,
            value_2 
        };
}
```

And I want to use this enum in B class:

```
public class B
{
 private A.myEnum[] tab = { A.myEnum.value_1, A.myEnum.value_2,  A.myEnum.value_1 ..}

}
```

I want to make an alias for:
 A.myEnum.value_1 and A.myEnum.value_2
so I could write

```
private A.myEnum[] tab = { alias_1, alias_2},
```

Comment: Why don't you pull the enum outside of class A?  Then you wouldn't have to use the class name.  It's normal to use the enum name and hacking it so you don't have the enum name could make the code confusing.

Comment: because I need this enum in A class. Plus its only example

Comment: Why do you need it defined inside of A?  If you make it public and put it in the same namespace you can still use it inside of A.  And as examples go you may have ended up describing an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I might be missing something, but:

```
public class B
{
    private const A.myEnum alias_1 = A.myEnum.value_1;
    private const A.myEnum alias_2 = A.myEnum.value_2;

    private A.myEnum[] tab = {alias_1, alias_2};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Using a helper method like

```
public static myEnum GetEnumName(string str)
{
    switch(str)
    {
        case "alias_1": return myEnum.Value_1;
        case "alias_2": return myEnum.Value_2;
        default: throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just could get all the values and turn them into an array:

```
myEnum[] tab = Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum)).Cast<myEnum>().ToArray();
```